# Sort Array by court and hour ascending

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How can i sort this array in php so that it stays sorted by court and hour in ascending order.

**The array is the following:**

```
    array(15) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Court 3"]=>
    string(5) "19h00"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Court 1"]=>
    string(5) "21h00"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Court 2"]=>
    string(5) "21h00"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Court 1"]=>
    string(5) "20h00"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Court 3"]=>
    string(5) "18h00"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Court 2"]=>
    string(5) "18h00"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Court 1"]=>
    string(5) "16h00"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Court 1"]=>
    string(5) "18h00"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Court 4"]=>
    string(5) "18h00"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Court 2"]=>
    string(5) "19h00"
  }
  [10]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Court 1"]=>
    string(5) "19h00"
  }
  [11]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Court 2"]=>
    string(5) "17h00"
  }
  [12]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Court 3"]=>
    string(5) "17h00"
  }
  [13]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Court 4"]=>
    string(5) "19h00"
  }
  [14]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Court 3"]=>
    string(5) "20h00"
  }
}
```

**My attempt was this one:**

```
asort($courtsHoras);
foreach($courtsHoras as $key => $value){
foreach($value as $key1 => $value1){
echo $value1;
}
}
```

**var_export() of the array**

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'Court 3' => '19h00', ), 1 => array ( 'Court 1' => '21h00', ), 2 => array ( 'Court 2' => '21h00', ), 3 => array ( 'Court 1' => '20h00', ), 4 => array ( 'Court 3' => '18h00', ), 5 => array ( 'Court 2' => '18h00', ), 6 => array ( 'Court 1' => '16h00', ), 7 => array ( 'Court 1' => '18h00', ), 8 => array ( 'Court 4' => '18h00', ), 9 => array ( 'Court 2' => '19h00', ), 10 => array ( 'Court 1' => '19h00', ), 11 => array ( 'Court 2' => '17h00', ), 12 => array ( 'Court 3' => '17h00', ), 13 => array ( 'Court 4' => '19h00', ), 14 => array ( 'Court 3' => '20h00', ), )
```

Comment: Always share a var_export() of your array, expected output and your attempt

Comment: Well, i shared a var_dump of the array, my attempt was to use sort, asort, ksort, i also tryed a custom function and usort, before a foreach loop, without luck. I edited the answer with the attempt.

Comment: Can you var_export(); you array? This is because it quickly helps us to copy paste your input array in our machines. Also,  can you share your expected output?

Comment: I edited the answer and included a var_export() of the array.

Comment: Expected output is (fiction values): court1 => 9h, 10h, 11h, 12h... Court2 => 9h, 11h, 12h, 14h, 16h... and so on for all four courts. I expect the ouput to be sorted acending in key court and value hour.
Example for court 4: Court 4 => 18h, 19h (hour must be from lower to greater).

Comment: So, the values in expected output has to be comma separated or you just wrote it short hand?

Comment: Thank you for the insights. I have already marked Code4R7 solution as the one that helped me accomplish the task.

Comment: I just added my version too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify the sorting process, you need to normalise the array keys before sorting.

For example:

```
$a = [
  ["Court 3" => "19h00"],
  ["Court 1" => "21h00"],
  ["Court 2" => "21h00"],
  ["Court 1" => "20h00"],
  ["Court 3" => "18h00"],
  ["Court 2" => "18h00"],
  ["Court 1" => "16h00"],
  ["Court 1" => "18h00"],
  ["Court 4" => "18h00"],
  ["Court 2" => "19h00"],
  ["Court 1" => "19h00"],
  ["Court 2" => "17h00"],
  ["Court 3" => "17h00"],
  ["Court 4" => "19h00"],
  ["Court 3" => "20h00"]
];
$b = [];
foreach($a as $ka => $va) {
  foreach($va as $kb => $vb) {$b[$kb][] = $vb;}
}
ksort($b);  // sort courts
foreach ($b as $k => $v) {sort($b[$k]);}  // sort hours
var_dump($b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`strnatcmp`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php) for this purpose along with [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). We first compare the `court {some_num}` key and if they are not equal, we return the result accordingly.

If they are same, we return the comparison of their timestamps.

```
usort($data,function($a,$b){
    $court_name_1 = array_keys($a)[0];
    $court_name_2 = array_keys($b)[0];
    $court_ordering = strnatcmp($court_name_1,$court_name_2);
    if($court_ordering === 0){
        return strnatcmp($a[$court_name_1],$b[$court_name_2]);
    }
    return  $court_ordering;
});
```

**Demo:** http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fe3330ceb671bac3984e062a6f784947a6f4e81e

Comment: Nice answer. I'm not used to this kind of sorting, I add an ORDER BY statement to my SQL queries instead.

Comment: @Code4R7 That would be the best way to solve it. If the task at hand is possible from an SQL query itself, there would be no need to do the same on the application server end.